# JavaFX 8. Resize of SplitPane within BorderPane

Tags: java, layout, javafx, javafx-8

I have the following layout in JavaFx 8 defined via .fxml:

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="730.0" prefWidth="1005.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <Pane fx:id="statusPane" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="1005.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </top>
   <center>
      <SplitPane fx:id="mainPane" dividerPositions="0.2" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1005.0"  minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <items>
            <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" hbarPolicy="ALWAYS" vbarPolicy="ALWAYS" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane fx:id="menuPane" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="200.0"  minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" />
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
            <ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" hbarPolicy="ALWAYS" vbarPolicy="ALWAYS"  minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane fx:id="formPane" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="800.0"  minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"/>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

I do not understand why SplitPane cannot get smaller than 1005x700 when user is resizing BorderPane during the runtime. SplitPane can get larger than 1005x700, which is fine, but it cannot get smaller than prefHeight and prefWidth, thought the Application window itself (BorderPane) can.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. I found the problem!

```
 minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"
```

generated by Scene Builder was a very bad idea!

The following code

```
 minHeight="0" minWidth="0"
```

works as expected!

So do not use `-Infinity` constant for the `minHeight` or `minWidth`. 0 is what you need!

Answer (score 1):

*The size of Layouts doesn't only depend on its size, but the size of the container(parent) / contents(children) as well*

**From Docs**

> A pane's parent will resize the pane within the pane's resizable range during layout.

The size of the SplitPane depends on its Parent. Since the `Width` of `BorderPane` is **1005.0** and `Height` is **730.0**. The SplitPane fills the Parent(which it is supposed to)

Try removing the

```
prefHeight="730.0" prefWidth="1005.0"
```

from the `BorderPane` in above fxml, you can find the SplitPane will decrease in height.

**Why only height?** It is because

```
<Pane fx:id="statusPane" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="1005.0" ..
```

forces the BorderPane to not decrease it's width.

*Parent has to resize itself depending on the size of its child.*

In short, if you are not sure how big or small your window can be, don't specify the `prefHeight` or `prefWidth` to your layouts